# Online source control

Tags: version-control

Basically, I am looking for an app like p4/svn that would be able to check in files to a secure ftp server or check out from an ftp server.

Are there any apps to do this? That way I wouldn't have to keep worrying about which computer/laptop has my most recently updated files.

Comment: Can I ask why you aren't using an SVN? That sounds like exactly what you need.

Comment: I only used p4 before, heard about svn but never used it. Just wanted to make sure to use whatever can do this. So svn does this?

Comment: Also by svn I have to use a client like Tortoise, right?

Comment: There are many clients available. One of the advantages of using a VCS that is free software :-): The popular ones are TortoiseSVN, the command line svn client, or plugins for various IDEs (Eclipse, VS, ...).

Comment: Thanks, what do you mean by VCS?

Comment: Version Control System. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control_system

Answer (score 2):

You can use SVN over HTTPS and access it externally.

**Edit:**
If you are looking to set up a new source control environment as your comments suggest. I would recommend [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/) which has the http stuff setup by default,

Answer (score 2):

[DropBox](https://www.getdropbox.com/home) automatically versions files and will give you 2 GB free. Not as fancy as hosted SVN, but very simple.

Alternatively, you can install SVN or GIT (or whatever) and point it at your DropBox file location.

Answer (score 1):

www.springloops.com is a hosted solution for svn.  I am using it and I find it pretty useful.

Answer (score 1):

The question appears unclear.

What do you mean by "check in files to a secure ftp"? All source control systems I know (at least Perforce, SVN, CVS) have a server component and a protocol of their own. So they can all work online, but with their *own* server.

What are you trying to do?

**Edit:**

Based on your comment, you want to use your web space. That will not allow you to do versioning and the other nice things a VCS (version control system) lets you do, like retrieving old versions, viewing history, merging changes to name just a few.

You can exchange files via HTTP/FTP, but if you want version control, you will need a server running a VCS software, such as Subversion, git or Mercurial. You can setup one yourself, but there are hosted solutions available (see other answers).

Comment: Basically store my files at my web space so I can check in/out files everywhere (on any computer).

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I thought a webspace would be able to accomodate the versioning, using a software. Do hosts not support these apps on their server?

Comment: No,  "webspace" usually means a web server (i.e. HTTP  server), which cannot do this. Many hosting providers do however also host version control servers, such as Subversion.

Answer (score 1):

Not a subversion solution though:
Combine [git-ftp](http://wiki.github.com/ezyang/git-ftp) with git and you are good to go. I would assume that there is something euqivalent for svn as well.

Answer (score 1):

At home, I use SVN with file protocol using a shared drive. Thus I can easily update from any of the computers in my house as long as the network and the file server are turned on. The documentation says they recommend against using file for production use, but I don't see why: It works fine for me.

At the office, we use SVN with http protocol, so we can access from anywhere you can reach the Internet.

SVN also has a custom protocol. We tried that briefly but there were no obvious advantages over using http.

As to clients: At home I use Subcommander for routine operations. If Subcommander is capable of creating new libraries and doing some other administrative functions, I don't know how to do it, so I fall back to command-line Subversion for admin stuff.

At the office we mostly use the Eclipse client. I use Tortoise for browsing.

The moral of the story being that there are lots of choices.

I'm not aware of any version control system that uses FTP, but I would think HTTP accomplishes the same thing. Of course you may have requirements I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Subversion and Git are both free and have a variety of different ways that you can connect and push/pull/checkin/checkout data.  In particular, they each have their own protocols which can be tunneled over SSH if you need security and they have HTTP/HTTPS access as well.

I don't quite follow the "Secure FTP", I'm guessing that is just a requirement that it be accessible remotely and in a secure manner.  Both git and svn would qualify and are nicely free.

SVN is more "mature" and has a greater number and more mature clients.

GIT is newer (the new shiny toy people want to play with), it's clients aren't quite as mature, but it has quite a few new cool features.  Also, every "checked out" version of git is itself a repository with a log and history.  This makes it quite powerful.